# X app over ssh server without X server

Tags: ssh, x11

in ssh with

```
 ssh -CX user@remoteA
```

I can launch a xterm and see in my local desktop.

if I have a linux server (remoteA) without X server and a remote linux desktop (remoteB) with a X server.
If I connect with ssh to remoteB over remoteA

```
local -ssh-> remoteA -ssh-> remoteB
```

how I can launch a xterm in remoteB and see in local ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup an end-to-end SSH connection, i.e. from `local` to `remoteB`, instead of chaining via `remoteA`. If you can't get to `remoteB` directly, either setup a port forward via `remoteA`, or use a `ProxyCommand`.

To use a port forward:

```
ssh -fNL 2222:remoteB:22 remoteA
ssh -Xp 2222 localhost
```

To use a `ProxyCommand`:

```
ssh -X -o "ProxyCommand=ssh remoteA nc %h %p" remoteB
```